# how to pass multiple parameter using same function in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[**Fiddle Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/fenqfff8/1/)

Here is my function I need to pass the multiple parameter dynamically with using same function. Is that possible to send the multiple parameter in ajax ?

```
function search_filter(getsearch){

    var headercolumn = getsearch.id;
    var columnvalue = getsearch.value;

      $.ajax({
      url: 'some_ajax.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {
          'headercolumn': headercolumn,
          'columnvalue': columnvalue
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
          console.log('success');
      }
  });
}
```

For now parameters are sending something like this, I mean one by one.

```
data: {
    'headercolumn': server,
    'columnvalue': givenvlue
},
```

**Expected Output**

I need to pass multiple parameters while calling the same function "*search_filter*"

```
data: {
    'headercolumn': server,media_server,eact_server
    'columnvalue': servervalue,media_servevalue,eact_servervalue
},
```

Hope you understand my needs. :)

Comment: You can pass an array i.e. `'headercolumn': [server,media_server,eact_server]`

Comment: Why not use arrays?

Comment: `headercolumn` and `columnvalue` are called parameters... Even in your expected output you are passing 2 parameters itself..

Comment: why not turn 'headercolumn' and 'columvalue' into arrays?

Comment: how to do that . Im using keyup function for all text box. can you pls give ne a demo ? @Satpal

Comment: I need to give the column name dynamically. how to do that in array @Mir

Comment: @QuestionUser neither is your fiddle complete.. not your question is.. you need to provide your HTML and other scripts..

Comment: pls check the updated fiddle @RajshekarReddy

Comment: Please add java-script at right place on fiddle link and provide css also

Comment: check the fiddle its working fine @KeertiSystematixInfotech

Comment: @QuestionUser I updated the fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/fenqfff8/4/

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `array`:

```
data: {
    'headercolumn': [server,media_server,eact_server]
    'columnvalue': [servervalue,media_servevalue,eact_servervalue]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that  array match your needs

```
 data: {
        'headercolumn': [server, media_server, eact_server],
        'columnvalue': [servervalue, media_servevalue, eact_servervalue]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to post all your `input` element's `id` and `value` when ever one of the input value changes..

I would recommend you to remove the `onkeypress` event handlers in the HTML elements, But rather add the even listener using Jquery. Keeping the code separate helps in better maintenance. Having said this you can use the below code.

```js
  $(function() { // wait for document ready event
    $('input').on('keyup', function() {  // bind keyup event to all inputs
      var headerArray = []; //have empty arrays
      var columnArray = [];

      $('input').each(function() {  //fill array values by looping all input elements
        headerArray.push($(this).attr('id')); //fill id's for header
        columnArray.push($(this).val());      //fill values for columns
      });

      //demo purpose
      console.log(headerArray);
      console.log(columnArray);
      //demo ends 
 
      $.ajax({
        url: 'some_ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
          'headercolumn': headerArray,
          'columnvalue': columnArray
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
          console.log('success');
        }
      });

    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="text" name="server" class="search_server" style="width: 94%" id="search_server">
</p>

<p>
  <input type="text" name="media_server" class="media_server" style="width: 94%" id="media_server">
</p>

<p>
  <input type="text" name="eact_server" class="eact_server" style="width: 94%" id="eact_server">
</p>
```

Comment: @QuestionUser didn't get you

Comment: @QuestionUser what I gave you was a suggestion, If you want to use your function `search_filter` itself then just call this function inside of `$('input').on('keyup', function() { ` also move all the code within this event handler to your function.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fenqfff8/6/)  I think your are trying to do something like

```
 $(function() {
    $('input').on('change', function() {
      var dataToSend={};
      $('input').each(function() {  
      dataToSend[$(this).attr('id')]=$(this).val();// create your object
      });

      $.ajax({
        url: 'some_ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data:dataToSend,
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
          console.log('success');
        }
      });

    });

  });
```